# Memory Allocation - Arduino

Tags: c++, memory, arduino, memory-mapped-files

I'm new to this low level stuff. I'm currently learning arduino. I'm currently using an Arduino Mega 2560 and in our course we are practicing memory management. I'm a pro at memory management in pc but somehow I'm having crazy problems here in arduino. For instance:

The arduino have 8192B, I'm trying to overflow it with uint_16 so I made an array of 8192/16 which is 512. so I did

```
uint16_t A[512+1];
```

Well I expected that to cause an overflow.

What is wrong with my concept?

Comment: A uint16_t has two byte, so why to you divide by 16?

Comment: _The arduino have 8192B_ Do you mean 8192Bit or do you mean 8192Byte = 8KByte?

Comment: yes I just broke the record of stupidity. I need a sleep.

Answer (score 3):

You seem to be confusing your bits for your bytes.

Assuming `sizeof (uint16_t)` is 2 on the Arduino, your array of 513 16-bit integers uses only 1026 bytes, which easily fits.

Answer (score 0):

Also in Arduino when the memory is full, you don't get any error or warning. The microcontroller just restarts.

Comment: well I keep track of the heap and stack.